# How to merge the dates into one column?

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datagrip

I have the year, month, day in separate columns and I want to merge them all into one column in snowflake

Comment: As display output, or into a new DB column?

Comment: Yes, as a display output

Comment: Look to [concat](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/concat.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select year||'-'||month||'-'||day from table
```

where year, month and day are column names for corresponding data.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the **DATE_FROM_PARTS** function:

```
select date_from_parts(1977, 8, 7);
```

Reference: [DATE_FROM_PARTS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_from_parts.html#date-from-parts)

Answer (score 0):

Create a string expression then use the To_Date Function.
For example:

```
set (day, month, year) = ('26', '10', '2021');
set strDate = concat(year, '-', month, '-', day);
select to_date(strDate)
```